# Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined in @lourenci/react-kanban when adding a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am testing a [react-kanban](https://github.com/lourenci/react-kanban) before I use it for my project. and I have created this code here at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dirac-ggv1i).

```
  import React,{useEffect , useState} from 'react'
  import Board, { addCard } from '@lourenci/react-kanban'
  import '@lourenci/react-kanban/dist/styles.css'

  export default function Index() {

    const [board, setBoard] = useState({
      columns: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Backlog',
          cards: [
            {
              id: 1,
              title: 'Add card',
              description: 'Add capability to add a card in a column'
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Doing',
          cards: [
            {
              id: 2,
              title: 'Drag-n-drop support',
              description: 'Move a card between the columns'
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    )
    const addcard =(e)=>{
      const newBoard = addCard(board,1,{
        id: 3,
        title: "dfdfdfdff",
        description: "SDfsfsf"
      })
      setBoard(newBoard)
    }

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fetch packages")
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={addcard} >Add Card</button>
          <Board>{board}</Board>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

the challenge is I am using their helpers to add a card to a column in a board but it's returning an error. what could I be doing wrong? or is it a bug?

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through the [documentation](https://github.com/lourenci/react-kanban#addcard) and unfortunately there's not enough example for how to use `addCard`. If you see below image, second parameter of `addCard` is `inColumn` but they didn't mention  what is the input, whether the column `id` or any other. So I tried to debug and figured out is `inColumn` is an `Object` with column `id`.

[image]

```
 const addcard = (e) => {
    const newBoard = addCard(board, { id: 1 } <-- this is the input of column, { 
      id: 2,
      title: "dfdfdfdff",
      description: "SDfsfsf"
    });
    setBoard({...newBoard});
  };
```

**Note: You need to handle the `id`s of each card manually as far I know**. Otherwise you'll see warnings in the console.

I have updated your example, it's working

[image: Edit new]

Comment: Great, and also interesting since other documentation of theirs implies that `addCard` isn't compatible with controlled boards. Nice work. I also found their level of API documentation rather poor. I'll leave my answer as an example for manually updating board data.

Answer (score 1):

You've a controlled board, so the `addCard` isn't valid according to their [props](https://github.com/lourenci/react-kanban#%EF%B8%8F-props) API documentation.

***Edit:** As answered by @Naren, the `addCard` utility *does* in fact work. I'm leaving my answer as an example of manually updating the data that is passed to the `Board` component that they simply "mirror".*

You need to manage the board data yourself. Here's an example `addcard` handler:

```
const addcard = (e) => {
  setBoard(board => ({
    ...board,
    columns: board.columns.map(column => column.id === 1 ? {
      ...column,
      cards: [...column.cards, {
        id: 3,
        title: "dfdfdfdff",
        description: "SDfsfsf"
      }]
    } : column)
  }));
};
```

[image: Edit cannot-read-property-cards-of-undefined-in-lourenci-react-kanban-when-adding]